# How to sum only a portion of a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to sum a portion of a tensor from top to bottom, and that portion depends on the value from another tensor.

For example: `L = [1,2,3]` and `I = [2.5]`

Then I want to get:  `1 + 2 + 3*0.5 = 4.5`

Another example:`L = [2,5,8]` and `I = [1.3]`

Then I want to get:  `2 + 5*0.3 = 3.5`

What kind of operation is this? Can I do this in `tensorflow`? ideally without using loops or conditional statement?

I would also like to do this in higher dimensions.

For example: `L = [[1,2,3],[2,5,8]]` and `I = [2.5, 1.3]`

Then I want to get:  `[4.5, 3.5]`

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import tensorflow as tf

L_tf = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,3),dtype=tf.float64)
I_tf = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,),dtype=tf.float64)

a = tf.sequence_mask(I_tf,L_tf.shape[1],dtype=tf.float64)
# [[1. 1. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]]
b = tf.sequence_mask(tf.ceil(I_tf),L_tf.shape[1],dtype=tf.float64)
# [[1. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 0.]]
c = tf.mod(tf.stack([I_tf]*L_tf.shape[1],axis=1),1)
# [[0.5 0.5 0.5]
#  [0.3 0.3 0.3]]
prod = tf.where(tf.not_equal(a,b),c,tf.zeros_like(a)) + a
# [[1.  1.  0.5]
#  [1.  0.3 0. ]]
result = tf.reduce_sum(L_tf*prod,axis=1)

L = [[1,2,3],[2,5,8]]
I = [2.5, 1.3]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result,feed_dict={L_tf:L,I_tf:I}))

[4.5 3.5]
```